# Parameterized Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Why do types in Haskell have to be explicitly parameterized in the type constructor parameter?

For example:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Here `a` has to be specified with the type. Why can't it be specified only in the constructor?

```
data Maybe = Nothing | Just a
```

Why did they make this choice from a design point of view? Is one better than the other?

I do understand that first is more strongly typed than the second, but there isn't even an option for the second one.

Edit :

Example function

```
data Maybe = Just a | Nothing

div :: (Int -> Int -> Maybe)
div a b
  | b == 0    = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (a / b)
```

Comment: In your example, would the types of `Just True` and `Just 42` be the same? If so, do you see any problems that would cause? If not, what do you think the difference would be?

Comment: I definitely see a problem, and I mentioned this in the post as well, that one is more strongly typed. However, since the second option is banned from Haskell I thought there would more reasons.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some pseudocode of how you'd use your version of `Maybe` (e.g., creating some values of it and then using them)? Then it would be easier to explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: It's not more "strongly" typed; it's *differently* typed. `data Maybe = ...` defines something of kind `Type`, while `data Maybe a = ...` defines something of kind `Type -> Type`. It's simpler to write different things in different ways, rather than having to infer which of two different things a single syntax is supposed to mean.

Comment: In particular, with the `ExistentialQuantification` and `RankNTypes` extensions, you can write `data EMaybe = ENothing | forall a. EJust a` and `data R2Maybe = R2Nothing | R2Just (forall a. a)`, and GHC will accept them. It might be illuminating to do that and then try some basic examples of `Maybe` adapted to them and see what happens.

Comment: Consider something like `data Either = Left a | Right b`. Are `Either String Int` and `Either Int String` the same? If so, what's the difference between `Left 3` and `Left "foo"`? If not, is `Left 3` correct or is `Left "foo"` correct?

Comment: The example you added at the end only shows _creating_ such value. But the second part of @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica's question was equally important: **how would you then use that value?**

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by using that value, wouldn't the ambiguity just propagate through functions?

Comment: Do you mean the omitted type parameter on the LHS of the declaration should be implicitly restored using all occurrences of parametric arguments on the RHS? As a consequence you couldn't determine the order of type parameters anymore and you'd need another syntax for existential types to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Why do we have to write `f x y = x+y` instead of `f = x+y`? Also, without explicit arguments, how do we distinguish between `data T a b = K (a -> b)` and `data T a b = K (b -> a)` ? We could adopt the convention that `a` is always the first argument and `b` the second one, but it looks fragile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would probably clear things up to use GADT notation, since the standard notation kind of mangles together the type- and value-level languages.

The standard `Maybe` type looks thus as a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Maybe a where
  Nothing :: Maybe a
  Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

The “un-parameterised” version is also possible:

```
data EMaybe where
  ENothing :: EMaybe
  EJust :: a -> EMaybe
```

(as Joseph Sible commented, this is called an *existential type*). And now you can define

```
foo :: Maybe Int
foo = Just 37

foo' :: EMaybe
foo' = EJust 37
```

Great, so why don't we just use `EMaybe` always?

Well, the problem is when you want to *use* such a value. With `Maybe` it's fine, you have full control of the contained type:

```
bhrar :: Maybe Int -> String
bhrar Nothing = "No number "
bhrar (Just i)
 | i<0        = "Negative "
 | otherwise  = replicate i ''
```

But what can you do with a value of type `EMaybe`? Not much, it turns out, because `EJust` contains a value of *some unknown type*. So whatever you try to use the value for, will be a type error, because the compiler has no way to confirm it's actually the right type.

```
bhrar :: EMaybe -> String
bhrar' (EJust i) = replicate i ''
  =====> Error couldn't match expected type Int with a
```

Comment: thanks for the example, it makes sense now. Now @ JosephSible-ReinstateMonica comments also make sense.

Answer (score 5):

If a variable is not reflected in the return type it is considered existential. This is possible to define `data ExMaybe = ExNothing | forall a. ExJust a` but the argument to `ExJust` is completely useless. `ExJust True` and `ExJust ()` both have type `ExMaybe` and are indistinguisable from the type system's perspective.

Here is the GADT syntax for both the original `Maybe` and the existential `ExMaybe`

```
{-# Language GADTs                    #-}
{-# Language LambdaCase               #-}
{-# Language PolyKinds                #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables      #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications         #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Prelude hiding (Maybe(..))

type Maybe :: Type -> Type
data Maybe a where
  Nothing ::      Maybe a
  Just    :: a -> Maybe a

type ExMaybe :: Type
data ExMaybe where
  ExNothing ::      ExMaybe
  ExJust    :: a -> ExMaybe
```

You're question is like asking why a function `f x = ..` needs to specify its argument, there is the option of making the type argument invisible but this is very odd but the argument is still there even if invisible.

```
-- >> :t JUST
-- JUST :: a -> MAYBE
-- >> :t JUST 'a'
-- JUST 'a' :: MAYBE
type MAYBE :: forall (a :: Type). Type
data MAYBE where
  NOTHING ::      MAYBE @a
  JUST    :: a -> MAYBE @a

mAYBE :: b -> (a -> b) -> MAYBE @a -> b
mAYBE nOTHING jUST = \case
  NOTHING -> nOTHING
  JUST a  -> jUST a
```

Comment: What extensions are needed to make these examples work? I am assuming it would need some non-trivial ones.

Comment: I added necessary extensions, `StandaloneKindSignatures` and `GADTs`/`GADTSyntax` are a good combo to understand more complex data types. They define a type in terms of its "type formation rules" (`:kind` output) and "term introduction rules" (`:type` output)

Answer (score 2):

Having explicit type parameters makes it much more expressive. You lose so much information without it. For example, how would you write the type of `map`? Or functors in general?

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This version says almost nothing about what’s going on

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [] -> []
```

Or even worse, `head`:

```
head ::  [] -> a
```

Now we suddenly have access to unsafe coerce and zero type safety at all.

```
unsafeCoerce :: a -> b
unsafeCoerce x = head [x]
```

But we don’t just lose safety, we also lose the ability to do some things. For example if we want to `read` something into a list or `Maybe`, we can no longer specify what kind of list we want.

```
read :: Read a => a

example :: [Int] -> String

main = do
  xs <- getLine
  putStringLine (example xs)
```

This program would be impossible to write without lists having an explicit type parameter. (Or rather, `read` would be unable to have different implementations for different list types, since content type is now opaque)

---

It is however, as was mentioned by others, still possible to define a similar type by using the `ExistentialQuantification` extension. But in those cases you are very limited in how you can use those data types, since you cannot know what they contain.